# Search pages with a Tag in CQ5

Tags: tags, aem

I am working on a custom search component in CQ5. I need to search for 1 or more tags selected by user using checkboxes. I tried using an earlier query to search text (select * from cq:Pagecontent where...)

I tried using :

```
select * from cq:PageContent where cq:tags like '%mytag%'
```

but it is not working. There are 2 pages which have 'mytag' as tag.

Any suggestion on how to do it ?

Comment: Your SQL syntax looks OK. Could paste a code excerpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is working for me. I'm searching here for for the following tags marketing:interest/services and marketing:interest/product

```
//element(*,cq:PageContent)[@cq:tags='marketing:interest/services' or @cq:tags='marketing:interest/product']
```

At the moment I would still go for XPATH, because of the better performance then SQL2. 
When searching for a tag I also would avoid wildcards as they are not necessary if you are searching for an exact tagname. 
Wildcards can negatively influence the performance of your query.